# Capture words that starts with characters

Tags: regex, posix

I would like to capture all space-separated words that starts with a set of characters.

For example, given `Th` + plattern, i would like to capture `This` and `That` in the sentence:

`This is. That is also.`

Using `POSIX` `regex` from the standard `c` lib.

Comment: What language??

Comment: `\bTh[\w]+` Would capture `Th` + any word character (`\w`)

Comment: Thanks @Duck, that works.

Comment: @Erlend I submitted it again as an answer. Would you mind marking it correct?

Comment: @Duck actually `\b` and `\w` doesn't actually work in POSIX c, but your example put me in the right direction - thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following ***Posix Regex*** pattern:

`(^|[[:space:]])Th[[:alnum:]]+([[:space:]]|$)`

Tested by *PHP Posix Regex Evaluator* on [**http://www.rexv.org/**](http://www.rexv.org/)

Comment: In my example i found `Th[a-zA-Z]+` to be sufficient, but i'll accept your answer as it probably works better in a general case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/\bTh\w+/
```

How does this work?

- `\b` matches a word boundary
- `\w` matches word characters

---

*NB, you might have to escape the backslash in programming language that use strings rather than literal regex, for example* `"\\bTh\\w+"`

Comment: What programming language?